# How to use multiple external names for outbound HELO in the EdgeSync outbound Send Connector?

Tags: exchange-2010, smtp

I have an Exchange 2010 environment where there are multiple Edge servers; the FQDN of each server ("serverX.domain.local") is different from the name used in the corresponding public MX record ("serverX.domain.com").

I have configured each server with two Receive Connectors, one for talking with the Hub servers (which uses the server's real name) and one for talking with the Internet (which uses the server's public name). This works as expected.

Howewer, the Send Connector created by EdgeSync for outbound messages is a global one, shared by all Edge servers; so it can only be configured with a single name to use for outbound HELO commands, or no one at all. If I leave the field blank, each Edge server will use its real (private) name. If I fill it in, each server will use the same name.

Is there any way to configure the outbound Send Connector so that each Edge server uses its public name in outbound HELO commands?

Comment: Short of not using EdgeSync and manually modifying the connectors I don't think so.  But reading this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997438%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx it seems that you might be able to suppress auto creation and be able to manually specify the send connectors still using EdgeSync, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do it, so I'm posting this "it's not possible" as the accepted answer.

If anyone can come up with a better answer, I'll be *very* glad to accept it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for this too.
The only way I found is to bind the SMTP connector to a different port, and NAT from the router with a set of IP/port to the connector's specific port...
It's ugly but it's working as long as you have a different IP for each domain...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any built-in way to do this with Exchange but you can do it with a 3rd party product: [MultiSendcon](http://www.servolutions.com/multisendcon.htm) allows you to have different outgoing HELO/EHLO domain names depending on the sender email address. You can also use it to route traffic to go out via different local IP addresses or through different smarthosts depending on the sender address or sender domain..